# Kubernetes calico on AWS ec2 instance not functioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, containerd

Just got a kubernetes cluster setup on an AWS ec2 instance with calico for networking and I'm receiving the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-195:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-57b57c56f-tn6rr    1/1     Running   0          25h
calico-node-dzntz                          0/1     Running   0          16m
calico-node-rrth4                          0/1     Running   0          16m
coredns-787d4945fb-jflls                   1/1     Running   0          25h
coredns-787d4945fb-ztdr5                   1/1     Running   0          25h
etcd-ip-172-31-12-195                      1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-12-195            1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-12-195   1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-proxy-4z867                           1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-proxy-fnknc                           1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-12-195            1/1     Running   0          25h
```

The describe shows the following errors:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  17m (x2 over 17m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: Error querying BIRD: unable to connect to BIRDv4 socket: dial unix /var/run/calico/bird.ctl: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  17m                kubelet            Readiness probe failed: 2023-07-24 09:44:49.390 [INFO][209] confd/health.go 180: Number of node(s) with BGP peering established = 0
calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with 172.31.6.112
  Warning  Unhealthy  17m  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: 2023-07-24 09:44:59.418 [INFO][237] confd/health.go 180: Number of node(s) with BGP peering established = 0
calico/node is not ready: BIRD is not ready: BGP not established with 172.31.6.112
  Warning  Unhealthy  17m  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: 2023-07-24 09:45:09.418 [INFO][269] confd/health.go 180: Number of node(s) with BGP peering established = 0
```

Here is my ip configuration on the ec2 instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-195:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:18:7b:c4:a6:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.12.195/20 metric 100 brd 172.31.15.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2477sec preferred_lft 2477sec
    inet6 fe80::818:7bff:fec4:a6df/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8981 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.151.128/32 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: cali1a02037d94e@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8981 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-a7ab184a-5f77-cd6f-7063-1826716eaaf6
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: cali246cfe27aa7@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8981 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-94919667-4b81-8940-6ae5-f978f648b597
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: cali69a17c198dd@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8981 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-2c28adf8-00e3-467d-ff99-dea734168c41
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```